# Give the relative difference in value between two items

Tags: java, compare

Give the relative difference in value between two items to allow the caller to figure out if a trade is worth it. (note this method is static).Note that the first item is assumed to be yours so the value returned is how much you would be ahead if you do the trade.

@param myItem first item to compare

@param theirItem second item to compare

@return the difference in current values between item 1 and item 2, -1 if either were nulls.

```
    public static double tradeItemCalculation(Item myItem, Item theirItem) {
    relativeValue = (theirItem - myItem) / myItem;
    return 0; 
}
```

How would I compare two items when I don't know the actual int value of those items and cannot create my own int value.

Comment: This won't compile; you can't subtract objects in Java. _Possibly_ there's some `Item.getXXXX()` method which returns number values which you can subtract. As you might think, we have _no idea_ of how the `Item` class looks like, so you'd need to provide additional details if you need more help.

Comment: It is a homework?

Comment: Yes, @ViacheslavVedenin it's homework; I saw virtually the same question not two days ago...

Comment: Yes it's a section within one of my assessments, I am not asking how to do it so I can copy and paste. I am just trying to get some assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Operator overloading isn't supported in Java. You can't just subtract two objects from each other. You'd have to do something like.

```
int diff = item1.getValue() - item2.getValue()
```

If you're using primitive int values then you'll never have a null for these, they will just default to 0. I'm not clear on the last part of your question, if you don't know the int value then surely it's just 0?

Comment: `int difference = (int) (myItem.getCurrentValue() - theirItem.getCurrentValue());`
`return difference;`

This currently works to an extent, it gets the value's of the items and subtracts them. Although something is wrong as the program that tests it is expecting -50 but is getting 50. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: If you are subtracting 2 items without checking which is larger you will unsurprisingly get a negative number out. If you don't care about the sign and just want an absolute value use `Math.abs(...)`.

Comment: `getCurrentValue()` returns the current value of the item. It all depends on another method which defines the item durability and creates the value.

Comment: Is that another java class? If it's dependant on another method then you need to make sure that is working as expected as well.

Comment: To find out how much **you** would be ahead, switch the subtraction around. 
Yours minus theirs tells you how much **they** are ahead.

Comment: Switching the subtraction around results in a `NullPointerException` error